# Use both @Named and @Stateless

Tags: jboss7.x, ejb-3.0, cdi, spring-test

I use JBoss to deploy my application that uses CDI & EJB.

- "applicationContext.xml" contains JTA datasource connection.
- "test-applicationContext.xml" contains RESOURCE_LOCAL datasource connection.

**=== Case 1 ====**

I have a CDI bean like this:

```
@Named
@Transactional
public class EmployeeRoleInserter {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = PersistenceConstants.PERSISTENCE_UNIT)
    private EntityManager entityManager;
...
}
```

and a JUnit Test like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:/test-applicationContext.xml"})
public class EmployeeRoleInserterTest {
    @Inject
    private EmployeeRoleInserter inserter;

    @Test
    public void testInsert() {
```

**The JUnit Test and the transaction works but the deployment on JBboss generates error:**

```
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: JBAS011469: Transaction is required to perform this operation (either use a transaction or extended persistence context)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.18.Final.jar:2.1.18.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.18-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    ... 25 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: JBAS011469: Transaction is required to perform this operation (either use a transaction or extended persistence context)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.AbstractEntityManager.transactionIsRequired(AbstractEntityManager.java:692) [jboss-as-jpa-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.AbstractEntityManager.persist(AbstractEntityManager.java:562) [jboss-as-jpa-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at com.devinition.policy.employee.registration.EmployeeRoleInserter.insertEmployee(EmployeeRoleInserter.java:52) [classes:]
    at com.devinition.policy.employee.registration.EmployeeRoleInserter.insert(EmployeeRoleInserter.java:33) [classes:]
    at com.devinition.policy.employee.registration.EmployeeRegistrationController.save(EmployeeRegistrationController.java:68) [classes:]
    at com.devinition.policy.employee.registration.EmployeeRegistrationController$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.save(EmployeeRegistrationController$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:258) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:39) [weld-core-1.1.10.Final.jar:2012-10-12 10:00]
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50) [weld-core-1.1.10.Final.jar:2012-10-12 10:00]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105) [jsf-impl-2.1.18-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.18.Final.jar:2.1.18.Final]
    ... 26 more
```

**=== Case 2 ====**

EJB bean:

```
@Stateless
public class EmployeeRoleInserter {     
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = PersistenceConstants.PERSISTENCE_UNIT)
    private EntityManager entityManager;
```

JUnit Test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:/test-applicationContext.xml"})
public class EmployeeRoleInserterTest {
    @EJB
    private EmployeeRoleInserter inserter;

    @Test
    public void testInsert() {
```

**The Test Case generates error:**

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.devinition.policy.employee.registration.EmployeeRoleInserter] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.ejb.EJB(beanName=, mappedName=, beanInterface=class java.lang.Object, description=, name=, lookup=)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1100)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:441)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:419)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$EjbRefElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:150)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:304)
    ... 26 more
```

**but the deployment on JBoss works well with transaction!**

**=== Case 3 ===**

Finally I mix both of them (CDI & EJB):

```
@Named
@Stateless
@Transactional
public class EmployeeRoleInserter {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = PersistenceConstants.PERSISTENCE_UNIT)
    private EntityManager entityManager;
```

JUnit

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:/test-applicationContext.xml"})
public class EmployeeRoleInserterTest {
    @Inject
    private EmployeeRoleInserter inserter;

    @Test
    public void testInsert() {
```

**The JUnit Test and transaction works well.**

**The deployment on JBoss works too but the transaction doesn't work! I mean the autocommit is like true**

`=> The question is "How can I make it work on both JBoss and JUnit Test???"`

Comment: It's not clear what you're doing. Spring Test does not work with CDI beans out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

in the `EmployeeRoleInserter` bean don't use the `@Transactional` annotation for the class but use it for the method which you are persisting the object inside it or 
put the CRUD operations in transaction `manualy`instead of using @Transaction annotation because `@Transaction puts the whole operations inside one transaction`